# Algorithms which proceed in a manner most similar to a PQ-based sort

Tags: algorithm, heap, priority-queue

So I'm attempting to figure out algorithms which proceed in a manner most similar to a PQ-based sort for the following structures.

- 1-heap
- 3-heap
- n-1 heap
- BST
- Balanced BST

For an example with heapsort and d-heaps. Heapsort uses a 2-heap as an intermediate representation to sort the contents. For heapsort, the PQ is a 2-heap even though any PQ would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a 1-heap. Using standard terminology, a 1-heap would be a heap with one child per node: a linked list. That wouldn't perform very well.

A 3-heap is just a [*d*-ary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap) where *d*=3. You say that heap sort uses a 2-heap. That's not always true. Many people implement heap sort with a 2-heap, often because they don't know that they could use a 3-heap. Which is unfortunate, because a 3-heap can be more efficient in many cases. I and many others *have* implemented heap sort with a 3-heap.

If by "n-1 heap" you mean a heap with n-1 children of the root, that's not going to be very efficient. With n-1 children of the root, when you remove the smallest item, you have to search all n-1 children to find the new root. You might as well just repeatedly search a linear list for the next largest item. An "n-1" heap sort will have the same performance as a selection sort.

A balanced binary search tree will perform better than an unbalanced one, but it's expensive to build the tree. The beauty of heap sort is that you can build the heap in O(n), in place. Building a BST is O(n log n). Although removing the smallest node is an O(log n) operation for both, real world performance favors the heap.

All that said, any data structure that can serve as a priority queue can be used in a pq-based sort. Binary heap (more generally, *d*-ary heap) is commonly used because it's easy to implement and very efficient. Depending on your application, though, something like [pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) could potentially outperform binary heap.